Facing issue with Inteillj on MAC OS Sequoia 15.2
I am using M1 Pro, after updating to Sequoia version 15.2, I am facing issue with IntelliJ. I am not able to open it. Before updating to Sequoia IntelliJ was working perfectly.
I have tried with multiple old version of IntelliJ, as well as new 2024.2 but still facing same issue. It is stuck on below screen.


Try solutions from this help article: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/articles/SUPPORT-A-58. If the issue persists, try reinstalling the IDE from scratch using Toolbox: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/installation-guide.html#toolbox. If it doesn't help, please send additional diagnostic data to JetBrains Support (Help | Contact Support) as requested at the end of the article.
